# VBA - IsNumber Returns Nothing Due to Prefix

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Follow Up Question from:

[VBA - Match Lookup With Multiple Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50227693/vba-match-lookup-with-multiple-parameters)

The code below works well, but I have since realized that the values in column A sometimes contain a prefix, which therefore returns nothing.

Hoping someone can edit the actually formula to account for a 2 letter prefix in front of the number.

***Code:***

```
Sub PlaceFormula()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim lc As Long

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set ws = Sheets("Main")
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lc = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

ws.Range("B2", ws.Cells(lr, lc)).Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2&B$1,INDEX(tStatus[[Employee Number]:[Employee Number]]&tStatus[[Wk Number]:[Wk Number]],),0)),""Match"","""")"
ws.Range("B2", ws.Cells(lr, lc)).Value = ws.Range("B2", ws.Cells(lr, lc)).Value

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Sample of data in Column A:

12345

24681

78956

AB12345

A78956

The data in the table will also contain  prefix IF the value is there.. So essentially, the MATCH is looking for an exact match.

Link to a sample file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uoa0Yn72nSckQaBnl6Y-a2q6UMJX6H3f/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please show some sample data

Comment: @Luuklag As in screenshots or do you want a link to a file?

Comment: Just some of the data that are in the column, you can just post as text in your question

Comment: are all the prefixes 2 chars?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Some might only be 1 char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this formula tells you if there is 2,1 or 0 non number prefixes. You can use the number that this formula produces to cut the prefixes off of the number and then conduct your match.

Formula 1:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(B2,1))),0,IF(ISNUMBER(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(B2,2),1))),1,2))
```

If the first char on the from left of the string is a number, return 0, if it is not check if the first char from the right of the string formed when taking the first two chars from the left of the string is a number, if that too is a number then return 2, else 1

Formula 2:

```
=RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-C2)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, your method will work but I think this might bring up some false positives as the data in the table also contains prefix'd numbers and non-prefix'd numbers, so it is very possible that after the prefix is removed, it might end up matching with the same number in the table but that does not necessarily meant that it is the correct number.

Apart from this, I recon I would need to apply the same method to my table so as to attempt to match 12356 with 123456 instead of trying to match 123456 with AB123456.

Comment: What I believe I meant to ask was to search for a string match instead of a number match.. However, I asked it incorrectly and you answered what I asked. So I will mark this as solved. Thank you for the effort :)